# ViTables Plotting Plugin

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

Hdf5View supports a very basic plotting feature. 
Although this feature is really simple, this has proven to be very useful to eyeball some data at first glance.

Does ViTables have a similar feature? If not does anybody know a good Plugin for plotting?
Thanks!

Comment: If you use pytables, you should be able to pull the data from the hdf5 tables into numpy arrays and plot it using matplotlib. If you are looking for a more ready made package with a GUI, I am not aware of any

Comment: Well, yes that is what I do anyway. Yet, it just would be nice to have a very, very basic plotting functionality directly within the ViTables viewer. Not to produce something sophisticated, just to eyeball data I gathered. This is a very convenient feature of HDF5View that you can quickly plot time series data.

Answer (score 0):

[Veusz](http://home.gna.org/veusz/) is able to plot data contained in HDF5 files. Unfortunately, it requires explicit importing of datasets, which might be cumbersome if you just want to quickly browse a HDF5 file.